# Instance of child in parent class

Tags: java

I have class In java: `A`. And class `B` which extends class `A`.

Class `A` hold instance of class `B`.

I notice that when I call the constructor of class `B` (when I init this parameter in class A),  It does super(), create a new instance of `A` and init all it fields.

How I can tell class `B` that the concrete instance of class `A` (which init it field) - it his parent class?

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  If an object has already been created, of class `A`, you can't then rebrand it and say that it's really an object of class `B`.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand especiall the last line. "How I can tell class B that the concrete instance of class A (which init it field) - it his parent class." 
??

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: You should provide some sample code to explain your problem.

Comment: composition and inheritance at the same time on the same classes... I dont think its a good programming practice. I dont see any real world example in which a parent class needs to have an instance of the class which extends it...

Comment: @MoritzPetersen - There is no pattern that uses  an object within itself...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really hard to understand, but I guess the problem is this this (your approach):

```
public class A {
    public B b = new B();
}

public class B extends A {
}
```

So, when you run `new A()` you get a `StackOverflowError`.

In my practical experience, I never needed a design like that, and I'd strongly recommend to re-think your approach. However, if it is really needed, you could use a dedicated `init()` method, e.g.:

```
public class A {
    public B b;

    public void init() {
        b = new B();
    }
}


A a = new A();
a.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you needed A within B you could just do it with a custom constructor for B:

```
class B extends A {

    A a;     

    public B() {
        super();
        this.a = this;
    }
}
```

This case is harder though so you need:

```
class A {
    B b;     
}

class B extends A {
     public B() {
         super();
         b = this;
     }
}
```

Note that you should not pass the B into the call to super() as B will not be initialized, you should do it as the last step in the constructor of B.

Comment: No, no, the question says that class `A` has an instance of class `B`, not the other way around.

Comment: yeah, just saw that - give me a sec

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP meant, but I'll remove my downvote anyway.

Comment: I dont see any real world example in which a parent class needs to have an instance of the class which extends it. is this a good practice?

Comment: @TheLostMind It's worse than that.  The OP has misunderstood how inheritance works.  He/she wants an instance of B which is actually the same object as an instance of A which has already been created; and worse still, he/she wants this instance to actually "have" itself.  None of it makes any sense, which is why both respondents have managed to misunderstand the question.

Comment: exactly... "Class A hold instance of class B."  -makes no sense. There is only one object, and like you said, "its like an object having an instance of itself". And I kept wondering if I had missed something.. :P

Comment: It's not just "like" an object having an instance of itself.  The OP exactly wants an object to have an instance of itself.  But he/she also wants to rebrand an existing object into a new class.  This is why I commented half an hour ago, that what the OP wanted wasn't how inheritance works.  But people went ahead and answered this non-question anyway.