# Why is Parent class init block executed?

Tags: java

As far as I know init block is a block that is executed before any constructor whenever that constructor is used for creating object.But why is the rule contradicts here...

```
class SuperClass
{
    SuperClass()
    {
        System.out.println("Super Class constructor");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Init block of super class");
    }
}

class Child extends SuperClass
{
    Child()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("Child Class constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Child c1=new Child();
    }
}
```

Here, as only child class object is formed, why is the init block of parent class called then?

Comment: It contradicts only if you think that the parent constructor won't be called if a `Child` instance is constructed. But 10 minutes of research would tell you, that this isn't the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instance of child in parent class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879487/instance-of-child-in-parent-class)

Answer (score 4):

`Child` is dependant on the parent class `SuperClass`. It gets / inherits properties  from the parent. So, to construct the child, the parent has to be constructed first. That is why `SuperClass`'s init blocks and constructors are called.

Comment: Can you answer me one thing is inheritance compile time or runtime..if it is compile time then it means parent class properties are inherited at compile time not runtime..that is not after creation of parent class object..

Comment: Asking whether something is compile time or runtime somewhat assumes that it is an event; inheritance is a concept, and has both compile time and runtime elements. When a child class is instantiated, things may happen to (or with) any parent classes.

Comment: @abhi - Inheritance works at both compile-time and runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can read through the [JLS 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) for this topic. Check step 3 and 4 of the initialization order

> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.

Answer (score 0):

Generally follow this rule,

class A{}
class B extends A{}

in this case,

while B-object instantiate, the sequence of calling is likewise,

B-Constructor -> A's Constructor -> before A's Constructor call A's All-Initialization block execute then A's Constructor then back to B's constructor like wise it works.

So, in your case,

Child object call to Child-constructor first,
but before go to it, it went to SuperClass-constructor, before proceed is first if any initialization block is there then it complete-here it's.

so SuperClass initialization block first execute then SuperClass's constructor and finally Child Constructor.